# Common Socket IO Controller in Node js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket io in my node server, where I initialized socket io in my server.js (which is my root file). This is what I’ve implemented,

```
const io = require('socket.io’)(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on(‘test1’, function(data) {

        io.sockets.emit(“test2”, data);

      }); });
```

The thing is, it is available only inside the server.js. In cases like where I want to emit my socket inside a controller, it becomes a bit complicated. So I’m thinking of separating the socket as a common file and utilize it inside the whole app. How do I achieve this, Suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as like below instructions:
1) First make a separate file for socketio
and use the code

```
const socket_io = require("socket.io");
const io = socket_io();

var Socket = {
emit: function(event, data) {
io.sockets.emit(event, data);
}
};

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
console.log("A user connected");
});
```

2)Now on your server file to initialize socket on server

```
const { io } = require("../utils/socket");
var server = http.createServer(app);

io.attach(server);
```

3)Now on your controller you can use `const { Socket } = require("../../utils/socket");` Just to import and use emit functions

Comment: It throws me an error, io.attach is not a function @Bibek